# function for add blank space after checking string minimum length

Tags: c#

Method for adding blank space after checking string minimum length,if string enter is not equal to minimum length defined then add blank space after the string to full fill the minimum length condition ? ?

example : minimum length =30

and string = "anuragsaraswat123abc"       20 character

then automatically find the diff between minimum length of string and available string and add blank space. Suggest me the method

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: Ill defined question. Please clarify what you wish to do.

Comment: If there is a minimum length requirement, isn't this just a hack to get around it? If it's not a requirement, surely you need to look at that rather than adding blank spaces?

Answer (score 9):

This is covered in the [framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx) with [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) and [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx)

```
string MyString = "Hello World!";
Console.WriteLine(MyString.PadRight(30, ' '));
```

Comment: but my string is is changed everytime...so how can i apply padright or left...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx) Method for that.

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by
>   padding them on the right with a specified Unicode character, for a
>   specified total length.

```
static string YourMethod(string s)
{
     return s.Length < 30 ? s.PadRight(30 - s.Length, ' ') : s;
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/xVGkex).

***Note***: Since you can't see the blanks, it doesn't mean they are not there `;)`

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
if (myStringVariable.Length < minimumLength)
    myStringVariable += new string(' ', myStringVariable.Length - minimumLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

receive the length and text you want or declare them and afterwards

```
 string strn = str.Length < length ? str.PadRight(length): str;
```

where str is the length you got/declared and length is the length got/declared
it's all in c# .net3.5 and up.

the whole code in c# winforms in the main func:

```
namespace AddSpacesAcctoLength
  {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
        public Form1()
          {
            InitializeComponent();
          }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int length = 20;
        string str = txtbxText.Text;

        string strn = str.Length < length ? str.PadRight(length): str;

        MessageBox.Show(strn + "hiyya" + strn.Length.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

goodluck

Comment: i declare the length of string

Answer (score 0):

From the first days of the NET framework (1.0) the string.PadRight and string.PadLeft has served well this problem.

Just use

```
string example = "Need 30 chars of length";
string result = example.PadRight(30, ' ');
Console.WriteLine("-" + result + "-" + "Length is:" + result.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if string.Length<30
{
n=30-string.Length;
for(int i=0;i++;i<n)
string+=" ";
}
```